# Calculating cumulative SUM in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, summarizing, qgsexpression

I'm trying to get the **cumulative sum** of the column `"uren_duur"` in a new column `"uren_tot"` based on the recorded water height `"NUMERIEKEWAARDE"`. The water height ranges from -194 to 262 and since this I'm trying to figure out the total time each water height has been submerged over a 3 month period. The column `"uren_duur"` contains the time submerged **per water height**.

So for the top row (*"NUMERIEKWAARDE" = 262*) the cumulative sum should be 0,166.. Then for *"NUMERIEKWAARDE" = 261* the cumulative sum should be 0,166..+ 0,166.. = 0,333, *257* should then be 0,166..+ 0,166..+ 0,166.. = 0,4999 and so on...

So when the height is -194 this should likely be around 2100 hours cumulative sum. I tried using this post ([Add cumulative sum column to attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312921/add-cumulative-sum-column-to-attribute-table)) as you can see in the expression bar but it wouldn't work for me.

This step is so easy to do in excel by just filling the first value (i.e. C1 = 1) and then using B2 + C1 to calculate C2 and just dragging the formula down. But I'm trying to automize a process in a small model so I don't want to perform this step manually.

[image: Here is the table with data I'm using.]

Comment: It should work. The expression in the screenshot seems wrong near the end, as your are referencing to another layer (`calulated_a28a...` instead of `uren_duur` (layer)) and another field (`NUMERIEKWAARDE` instead of `uren_duur` (attribute))

Comment: See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412928/calculating-cumulative-line-length-on-large-dataset/412941#412941) for an alternative method using a virtual layer, where you can specify the sort order too

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

To calculate the cumulative sum of the field `"value"`, based on a condition of the field `"order"`, create `"order"` as a variable that you can refer to in the filter condition of the [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#sum) function. Like this:

```
with_variable (
    'order',
    order,
    sum( value, filter:=order<=@order)
    )
```

[image]

You can add further conditions to the filter condition, like only calculate the cumulative sum based on order field and if the value of field `"id"` can be divided by 3:

```
with_variable (
    'order',
    order,
    sum(value, filter:=order<=@order and id%3 = 0)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this works for me! :)

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 5):

In your [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), you can also try this. The `"id"` field is your order by field and `"uren"` the sum field.

```
with_variable(
    'id1',
    "id",
    round(array_sum(array_agg("uren", @id1 >= "id")), 2)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an expression which does that. You need two fields:

- A field that contains the order of your cumulation `"your order field"`
- A field that contains the number you want the sum of `"your sum field"`

```sql
array_sum(
 array_slice(
  array_agg("your sum field",order_by:="your order field"),
  0,
  array_find(
   array_agg($id,order_by:="your order field"),
   $id
  )
 )
)
```